# Client closed connection before receiving entire response - onClick Tracking Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, tracking

I have this tracking function:

```
function trackMe(link, myID) {

    var trackPath = "http://www.theurl.com" + myID + "&size=1x1";

    var img = $('<img>');
    img.attr('src', trackPath);
    img.appendTo('div.promo');

}
```

Which is fired from an href as so:

```
<a href="http://www.togolink.com" onclick="trackMe(this, 'SpecialCode1');">Buy</a>
```

In Charles proxy, I receive the following error when I click on the href:

```
Client closed connection before receiving entire response
```

And the tracking pixel is not sent/received properly.

Any idea what would be causing this?

Comment: Does the third paragraph on this site help? http://blog.skinkers.com/2010/06/15/flex-file-upload-with-php-issue-uploadcompletedata-has-empty-data/

Comment: No, this is static html. But thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the `href="#"` because this is being directed to `http://www.togolink.com` on click

```
<a href="#" onclick="trackMe(this, 'SpecialCode1');">Buy</a>
```

Also i think there should be a somemore thing between the link and myID something like

```
"http://www.theurl.com?id=" + myID + "&size=1x1";
```

Most important thing is, since you are already using `jquery` why are you using `inline` `javascript` why not `jquery click event handler`.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" link="http://www.theurl.com" id="SpecialCode1">Buy</a>
//you can change value of for attribute as per your requirement.
```

**jquery:**

```
$('a#SpecialCode1').click(function(){
    var link = $(this).attr("link");
    var myID = $(this).attr("id");
    var trackPath = link + myID + "&size=1x1";
    var img = $('<img>');
    img.attr('src', trackPath);
    img.appendTo('div.promo');
    window.location = link ;
});
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/U4C5T/1/)**

Comment: Disabling the href passes a successful code. However, when I do `window.location = link.href;` I receive the error code again

Comment: No, sorry. That doesn't work. Although strangely, if I add an alert in there, it returns a `success` message (although now there is an alert):

`$('a#buy').click(function(){
    var img = $('<img>');
    img.attr('src', $(this).attr("for"));
    img.appendTo('div.promo');
    alert("Success");
});`

Comment: I disable the href then pass the link back as `window.location = link.href;` and even tried a delay such as `window.location = link.href, 9000;`. `trackPath` is simply an image that is generated and not the link that should be followed.

Comment: what you want to do actually??? are you trying to load the image and then go to the link ???

Comment: Yes, and that's what happens. But the tracking pixel returns a failure that `Client closed connection before receiving entire response`.

Comment: okay got you.. updated the answer.. check it now..hope this time it will help you.